# Correct in app-purchasing local currency symbol

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, currency, nslocale

With in app purchasing I want the local currency symbol to obviously suit the users local currency. Is it safe to use NSLocaleCurrencySymbol as the main source of detection of where the user is. Heres part of my code:

```
         NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
     NSString *symbol = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
     NSString *cost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",product.price];
```

By default is the correct Region Format automatically done in the International settings on each device when a user purchases an iOS device ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use a [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

**Objective-C**

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setLocale:product.priceLocale]; 
NSString *cost = [formatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

**Swift**

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.locale = product.priceLocale
let cost = formatter.stringFromNumber(product.price)
```

This will then format the currency with the correct decimalisation, separator and currency symbol.

Comment: Is there a way of testing this because if I change the international settings on my iphone my in app purchase alway shows a UK (£) currency symbol ??

Comment: It uses the locale (and therefore currency) of the `SKProduct` not the device so you are actually testing it :)

Comment: Ok, so is there a way of testing the currency symbol ?

Comment: You are testing it in a way, as if you changed the international settings and it doesn't change the currency symbol it is working. I suppose you might be able to find a international setting that has a currency that also uses pounds and then the UI might show `GBP` instead as showing £ would confuse users. Like US$ and AUS$.

Comment: Create a test account in a different store (you can set the country when opening a test account). this way you could see if the currency is OK.

Comment: @Rich ! Thank you for posting this. Quick question , this will always return the final price + symbol (0.99$,1.99$) etc" price + symbol?

Comment: @RoiMulia yep it will

Answer (score 4):

Updated to Swift 3.0 and as an extension of SKProduct:

```
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {
    func getLocalizedPrice()->String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        if let formated = formatter.string(from: self.price) {
            return formated
        } else {
            return "\(self.price)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just keep in mind that the formatter's `string(from: Number)`  method returns an optional, so you need to either specify `String?` as the return type or force unwrap before returning.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that,The `SKProduct` comes with a local of the user store, you can use -

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Look here -

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/price)

Comment: thanks for your help - but whatever regional format I set my iPhone to it always comes out as my local currency (£). For example, on my iPhone if I set the region Format as United States - when I test my in app purchase it still says £ (pounds)  not $ dollars ??

Comment: Yes because the format of the SKProduct is set by the App Store country that the user is logged in to. If you try to set the local yourself you will present the users the wrong price. The way you should test it is to open a test account in other app store and check the currency.

Answer (score 2):

In swift

```
var currency_format = NSNumberFormatter()
currency_format.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
currency_format.locale = validProduct.priceLocale
mylabel.text = currency_format.stringFromNumber(validProduct.price)
```